# Streaming/Triggering the file download via REST api

Tags: php, file, api, rest, download

I am developing REST API. One of the calls should allow downloading the file. 
The API call is like this:

```
 /music/mp3s/jenkins/12/
```

12 is the file_id stored in the dataabse. The actual filename is generated from the database record for this file. Something like `jenkin_494_334_12.mp3`. The file id is appended at the end of the filename part.

However, this file is not accessible directly through an URL. Its stored outside of the webroot. How do I stream/trigger the download via REST API call above.

If it were a webspage, we can all PHP file and then issue a `header` call to trigger the download.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps set the mime type?